# I dont get why the reaction role wont do anything?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I've been trying to set up a bot that gives a new user who joined my discord server the role "mietzekatze" when he reacts with ":white_check_mark:" to a message. It's like a type of verification or approval. So I found a  solution on how to do that, but it does not work. I tried different things, but it won't work. It doesn't return any error, it just wont do, what it's supposed to. Please help, I'm losing my mind.

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, member):
    Channel = client.get_channel('828667703966433331')
    if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
        return
    if reaction.emoji == ":white_check_mark:":
        Role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="mietzekatze")
        await member.add_roles(Role)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different event here called `on_raw_reaction_add`. For that you also need `payload`. You can read the docs for that [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw_reaction#discord.on_raw_reaction_add).

**Re-written your code would look like this:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id) # Get the guild
    if payload.channel_id == Channel_ID_here: # If the defined channel is correct
        if str(payload.emoji) == "✅":
            role = get(payload.member.guild.roles, name='mietzekatze') # Or id='RoleID'
        else:
            role = get(guild.roles, name=payload.emoji)
        if role is not None:
            await payload.member.add_roles(role) # Add the role
            print("Added role") # Check if the role was added
```

- You can use as many `if str(payload.emoji) == "YourEmoji":` events as you want, just pass them under the other event(s).
- Note that you have to pass the ID of a channel/guild without `' '`

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. The bot just doesn't appoint any roles... Don't worry, I did give him the administrator option.

Comment: Have you enabled the Intents?

Answer (score -1):

You have to check for channel's id

```py
if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel.id:
        return
```

Comment: Please have a look at the full code. There were more mistakes that should have been corrected.